trying to test my Lambda function but keep getting this error "errorMessage": "\"[object Object]\" is not valid JSON",
I am making a lambda function for my react app. Its actually a video streaming service. The users can upload video through the react app using the upload button. The upload button in the react app should trigger a lambda function in AWS to get a presigned url to putObject inside the S3 BUCKET. What i am doing wrong here???? THis is my lambda code
import { S3Client, ListBucketsCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";

const bucketName = "temp-videobucket-hls";

export const handler = async (event) => {
    const body = JSON.parse(event.body);
    const { fileName, fileType } = body;

    const params = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: fileName,
        Expires: 60,
        ContentType: fileType
    };
    console.log("to check if this is actually working")
    try {
        const uploadUrl =  S3Client.getSignedUrl('putObject', params);
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify({ uploadUrl })
        };
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error generating pre-signed URL', err);
        return {
            statusCode: 500,
            body: JSON.stringify({ error: 'Failed to generate pre-signed URL' })
        };
    }
};


and this is the api template i am sending to test the deployed lambda function
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "routeKey": "$default",
  "rawPath": "/path/to/resource",
  "rawQueryString": "parameter1=value1&parameter1=value2&parameter2=value",
  "cookies": [
    "cookie1",
    "cookie2"
  ],
  "headers": {
    "Header1": "value1",
    "Header2": "value1,value2"
  },
  "queryStringParameters": {
    "parameter1": "value1,value2",
    "parameter2": "value"
  },
  "requestContext": {
    "accountId": "123456789012",
    "apiId": "api-id",
    "authentication": {
      "clientCert": {
        "clientCertPem": "CERT_CONTENT",
        "subjectDN": "www.example.com",
        "issuerDN": "Example issuer",
        "serialNumber": "a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1",
        "validity": {
          "notBefore": "May 28 12:30:02 2019 GMT",
          "notAfter": "Aug  5 09:36:04 2021 GMT"
        }
      }
    },
    "authorizer": {
      "jwt": {
        "claims": {
          "claim1": "value1",
          "claim2": "value2"
        },
        "scopes": [
          "scope1",
          "scope2"
        ]
      }
    },
    "domainName": "id.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
    "domainPrefix": "id",
    "http": {
      "method": "POST",
      "path": "/path/to/resource",
      "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
      "sourceIp": "192.168.0.1/32",
      "userAgent": "agent"
    },
    "requestId": "id",
    "routeKey": "$default",
    "stage": "$default",
    "time": "12/Mar/2020:19:03:58 +0000",
    "timeEpoch": 1583348638390
  },
  "body": {
    "fileName": "value1.mp4",
    "fileType": "video/mp4"
  },
  "pathParameters": {
    "parameter1": "value1"
  },
  "isBase64Encoded": true,
  "stageVariables": {
    "stageVariable1": "value1",
    "stageVariable2": "value2"
  }
}

!
The problem should be inside the body object but all the other values in the request are written the same way.
The error suggests that the problem occurs when the code tries to parse JSON in the line#6 of my code, but I cannot figure out why this JSON format is incorrect?

The error message is quite helpful here. It's presumably because event.body is not a JSON string. It's a JavaScript object, likely deserialized from the original JSON. Try const { fileName, fileType } = event.body; Also, print the event to see what it actually contains.

destructuring event.body directly solved the issue. Thanks

Solved the issue by destructuring the event.body object without applying json.parse by directly using
const {fileName, fileType} = event.body;

Plus this code does not work as intended. For anyone else stuck here, use the following code to get presignedurl. There is an article explaining this here article


import { S3Client, PutObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { getSignedUrl } from "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner";

const generateWebFormS3URL = async (event) => {
  try {
    let REGION = "<REGION-NAME>";
    let BUCKET = "<BUCKET-NAME>";
    let KEY = event.key;

    const client = new S3Client({ region: REGION });
    const command = new PutObjectCommand({ Bucket: BUCKET, Key: KEY });
    
    const presignedUrl = await getSignedUrl(client, command, { expiresIn: 360 });
    console.log("Presigned URL:", presignedUrl);
    
    return {
      status: "Success",
      message: presignedUrl
    };
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    throw new Error(err);
  }
};



